# How to map an Image on a plane manually?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to put an image onto a plane. I've used the Import Image as Plane add-on, but I'd like to know how to do it myself. I tried setting my image as the texture for the plane, but it appeared stretched. I think that I need to adjust some mapping setting. Thanks!

Comment: You have to unwrap you mesh and make sure its size matches the image proportions. Might be hard to do precisely by hand alone

Comment: One thing might do to get the dimensions of the plane right is to look at the resolution of the image and use that to set the x and y dimensions of the plane. You can scale the plane down (it will probably be pretty huge) from there.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos All you need to do is type the numbers for the dimensions in the proper edit field. What do you mean "might be hard"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open your image in the UV/Image editor, Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the side panel. In the image section you can see the image's dimensions in pixels.

[image]

Add a plane and scale it so that it has the same proportions of your image.

Int this example the image is 1728 x 2592 pixels, so I scaled the plane to

1.728 x 2.592[image]

At this point press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply the scale. (for more on this read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data))

Then go to top view. Enter edit mode, press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap the UVs and select "**Project From View (bounds)**".

[image]

That will create a UV map that matches with the image used.

[image]

Then, just create a material that uses an image texture, and select the image you are using as a source, using UV as the mapping coordinates.

For Cycles:

[image]

For Blender Internal:
[image]

After doing all of this, you might want to save all of the trouble and just use the "add images as planes" addon, that does all of this for you atomatically, but at least you know what happens behind the scenes...

Comment: Minor typo: *select "unwrap from view (bounds)"* should be *select "Project from View (Bounds)"*. :)