# Applying texture to plane: Get rid of diagonal repeat pattern

Tags: texturing, uv

I wanted to add an image to a plane. Here is what I tried:

- Created a new plane
- Added a new material and added a texture
- Selected .png

and this is what I get

[image]

And this is what is shown in the preview:

[image]

Why am I getting the diagonal pattern? And why is it applied by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map an Image on a plane manually?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81042/how-to-map-an-image-on-a-plane-manually)

Comment: @cegaton Edited the title

Comment: Are you using Cycles? Have you unwrapped the plane?

Comment: Read the link. What you are missing are mapping coordinates. The most precise way to map an image is using UV maps.

Comment: But isn't it stupid to have diagonally rotated repeating pattern applied by default in the absence of an explicit UV map?

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Import Images as Planes add-on" that ships with Blender, and try importing the image directly already mapped that way - it helps avoid weird problems that occur. I use it even to do cutaways later.