# Imported image is not showing in render

Tags: animation, image

I have a imported image in a scene in blender. Yet when I render the image.

[image]

This is what I get:
[image: omp]

Comment: Add the image to question that you are trying to import!

Comment: i will try, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Images added to be used as "reference" or as "background" will not render, they are reference only. The same is valid for Images used as empties. Think of those images as "virtual" or "auxiliary objects" or with no renderable attributes (like a surface or material).

[image]

If you want a plane that uses an image as a texture then you have to enable the "add images as planes" addon in the preferences window.

[image]

Now you can add an image as plane. The difference is that this addon will create real object: a plane with 4 vertices and a face that uses the image as a textures on the material. This new object is renderable.

[image]

Read also: [How to map an Image on a plane manually?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81042/how-to-map-an-image-on-a-plane-manually/81047#81047)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

## Try images as planes!

First things first: Go into Preferences,

[image: Preferences]

Select Addons then search for "Image"

[image: Addons Image as Planes]

Now tick the box, then now in "Add" you will see "Images as Planes"

[image: Add version]

It is also accessible from:
File > Import > Images as Planes

[image: Import version]