# Images as planes VS uv mapping

Tags: uv, image

On the left cube I have added an image(PNG) as a plane, and snapped it on the face of the cube, and on the right cube I have UV mapped the image(PNG). Now the image as plane, leaves some weird shading issues, depending on the angle, and light, where as the UV mapped image, there's no problem at all. But is there a way around this to get the image as plane to look as good quality like a UV mapped image? The reason why I snapped it on the face of the cube, was to avoid UV mapping as a solution and avoid setting up Nodes.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "snapped it on the face of the cube"? That looks like z-buffer fighting to me. Maybe you could delete/mask the underlying cube face?

Comment: As far as I know, the main difference is that Images As Planes comes pre-setup with alpha enabled. For this, it has the Blend Mode preset to Alpha-Blend, where a new UV mapped texture will have it's Blend Mode set to "opaque" by default.

Comment: Don't do that. There is no need to snap a plane over other faces, you are just creating Z-fighting for no reason. Map the texture over the faces of the cube. Don't avoid nodes, learn how to use them and be happy.

Comment: Ok guys, I wasn't being lazy, I was just experimenting with various options. After all the only thing I need to add in the Nodes is an image texture and UV the image on the cube. I was after some information in case this was another way of quickly UV mapping images on a mesh. I have seen people using Boolean methods, which makes an awful mesh topology, tris & Ngons and I've always asked myself how do they UV images on that mesh, the image would break up into multiple scattered pieces all over the UV, So I thought this would be the answer.

Comment: Quickest way is *project from view* in this case. However, if you have the time just create proper uv's...

Comment: Avoid booleans like the coronavirus. Avoid stacking up surfaces over each other to prevent z-fighting. You don't UV images, you create an UV map, and the coordinates of such map are used to place the image as texture on a material. If you are learning to use blender start with the basic concepts, and do the work before you learn shortcuts. You might be interested in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/how-do-texture-coordinates-work/23174#23174

Comment: Read this one too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81042/how-to-map-an-image-on-a-plane-manually/81047#81047